# Javascript generate unique short code from an existing unique code

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uniqueidentifier

Given that I already have a guaranteed unique string, is it possible to generate a shorter version of this string while keeping the newly generated strings also unique?

The existing unique code is the id generated by firebase firestore, the ID is too long and I prefer not to use it as referral code. I was hoping to limit the length of the string around 8-10 chars.

EX of firebase id: `NIzTFZUC64Voc4ttiiNsBF0GNWF3`

I need a much shorter version of this string

I also don't want the codes to be case sensitive

Comment: The number of unique 8-10 character strings (in a more limited character set) is *astronomically* smaller than the number of unique strings as long as your example.

Comment: @Pointy correct but isn't that what url shortners do?

Comment: Yes but they map through a database. You could do that.

Comment: I can, but I was hoping to keep this as simple as possible, if possible